# save checkbox values to database in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, checkbox

I am working on a project in which i have to save the status and value(which data's checkbox has been clicked?) of checkbox into database. for eg:- if we checked on checkbox then it's current status should be saved in databse 
here is my code

```
<?php
                        //get rows query
$query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM bankstatement");
if($query->num_rows > 0){ 
$i=0;
while($row = $query->fetch_assoc()){
?>
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <tr>
  <td><?php echo $row['cdate']; ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $row['particulars']; ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $row['reference']; ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $row['deposits']; ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $row['withdrawals']; ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $row['bankname']; ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $row['status']; ?></td>
  <td><input type="checkbox" name="ch[$i++]"/><label for="reconcile bank stmt"></label></td>
  </tr>
 </form>
<?php } }else{ ?>
<tr>
<td colspan="8">No record(s) found.....</td></tr>
 <?php } ?>
```

Now please suggest me thaqt how can i do this??
Thanks in advance.

Comment: set the value for checkbox and read it

Comment: 1) You don't have any value in the checkbox 2) the 'ch[$i++]' is invalid because it's outside of the PHP engine. 3) To update a SQL you need to pass back some kind of primary key, I don't see that here.

Comment: You didn't show  any error or problem which is a bad idea. Then if you want a suggestion that will be run the program and check what kind of error you are getting and then ask about the error.